# Data on Medicare Advantage Plans

Tags: data.gov

I'm looking for data on Medicare Advantage Plans: eligibility, cost, coverage, etc. Where can I find it/

Comment: In addition to [medicare.gov](https://www.medicare.gov/plan-compare/#/?lang=en), a quick Google search shows many sites that let you search for plans by zip code.  What is the geographic and temporal scope you need?  Are you looking for a single database that combines all potential plans given a consumer's characteristics?

Answer (score 0):

The plan finder on [Medicare.gov](https://www.medicare.gov/plan-compare/) has some of the information you seek.  It is only a general overview, however.  It is missing some of the specifics, such as costs for certain types of medical care.  I have used it to help some people in the USA find appropriate coverage.  When doing so, I did find some of the information to be inaccurate.  I also found that sometimes wide ranges of costs were presented for some medical care/treatments/procedures, which was not helpful.  For example, I once saw something like $0-$800 specified for a plan's medical imaging copay.

The following website has data on estimated costs, by region in the USA, based on approximate anticipated health status: http://www.medicarenewswatch.com/index.php/en/cost-comparisons

Here is the FAQ explaining the data presented on that website: http://www.medicarenewswatch.com/index.php/en/faq

I am currently unaware of any data source that contains comprehensive, accurate, and detailed Medicare Advantage Plan information.  If someone is aware of such a data source, I encourage them to add another answer.